# Is it possible to call a function and show values in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `data-ng-repeat` in my html code, is it possible to show the data within the {{}} and at the same time, call a function with the same variable?

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Month</th>
  <th data-ng-repeat="column in columns" data-ng-show="channels.indexOf(column.field) > -1" ng-if="column.visible">{{ column.title }}</th>
  <th>Temperature (&deg;C)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in tableData">
  <th>{{ data.month }}</th>
  <td data-ng-repeat="column in columns" data-ng-show="channels.indexOf(column.field) > -1" ng-if="column.visible">{{ data[column.field] | formatNumber:2}}</td>
  <td>{{ data.temperature | formatNumber:1 }}</td>
</tr>
```

In this case, I would like to use the `data[column.field]` in another function in the backend.

Comment: Do you mean ng-click attribute it lets you define a click action  ? You can read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: @katmanco No, I get a whole bunch of data from the backend and show a portion of it in the table. Now I want to use the values I put in the table, but I dont know how to display them _and_ parse to the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a function from the template using

```html
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in tableData">
  <th>{{ data.month }}</th>
  <td data-ng-repeat="column in columns" data-ng-show="channels.indexOf(column.field) > -1" ng-if="column.visible">{{ data[column.field] | formatNumber:2}}</td>
  <td>{{ myfunction(data[column.field])}}{{ data.temperature | formatNumber:1 }}</td>
</tr>
```